# Using of ContourGenerate in PyQGIS

Tags: contour, gdal-contour

Can anyone help explain me how to use the `ContourGenerate` method of GDAL.

The official documentation states two sets of arguments for the method, with one being

```
ContourGenerate ( **args, ***kwargs )
```

And the other being:

```
ContourGenerate(Band srcBand, double contourInterval, double contourBase, int fixedLevelCount, int useNoData, double noDataValue, Layer dstLayer, int idField, int elevField, GDALProgressFunc callback=0, void * callback_data=None)
```

I do not understand how this is supposed to work.

I tried working my way by trial and error method, by intentionally leaving out the arguments and filling them as per the demands of error message. The method kinda worked, by asking me the arguments of second definition (in the same order as given above). This worked up until I entered `elevField = -1`, and then it just gives an error message:

> TypeError: not a sequence

I tried googling the error but to no avail. I also tried including the `callback=0, callback_data=None` part in the argument list, but the same error occurs.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: You can find usage examples from the GDAL autotest suite https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/alg/contour.py.

Comment: @user30184, i went through the link, and tried to produce a similar code to check if its working for me. However, the does not work, and gives the following error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateField'`

This error is refering to line 91 (and also line 93).


I did manage to work around the TypeError as asked in the Question (turns out i was using source layer as destination layer all this time), only to get an error:
`ValueError: Received a NULL pointer.`